# Add 1 hit to article on click function joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

Hi guys i have some trouble here.

```
 <a class="anything" href="another/website">Take me to this product</a>
```

This button or link over here is added to every article  in my joomla site and i have constructed every article to display diffrent products, and the link will take me to the product in my webshop.

My problem here is i need to have a toplist on my site based on article hits.

Basicly i want the link up there to add one hit to the specific article its in onClick

Answer (score 0):

You could display **articles** in a **module** using:

- Articles Category Module
- Articles - Newsflash Module

Both have an option to **Order Results** by **Hits**.

To get the **url part** from **module output** you have to open module code and add a **[preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match)** that would search for `<a> ... </a>` part.

An example would be:

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/<a.*?>(.*)<\/a>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $url); // $string would contain module output
    print_r($url);
?>
```

This tutorial may also help you: [Find URLs in Text, Make Links](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/).